# Why there is no reverse search in kde5 okular

Tags: latex, okular

I have updated some time ago to kubuntu 15.04 and sadly realized that somehow reverse search for latex-synctex disappeared from Okular. I mean, the settings are there, just the left click doesn't work any longer.

Kubuntu 15.04 uses Okular 0.21.3, but I found nothing mentioning it in Okular's web page.

Does someone encountered the same problem? Or alternatively, is there anyone who uses Plasma 5 with Kubunut 15.04 and succeeds with reverse search in Okular?

Thanks.